# Smarty if/else using Post Parameters?

Tags: php, parameters, smarty

I'm using the Smarty template system and can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this...

I want to check what parameters are sent through Post.  If the parameters `last7`, `last30`, `last60`, or `full` DO NOT exist, I want to display `"This is not working!"`.  If any of those parameters have been posted, I want `"This is working"` to be displayed.

Does anyone know how to do this in the Smarty template system?

The Smarty docs don't have any info that I can find on using if/else with parameters...

Comment: What do you mean by `if/else with parameters` ?

Comment: I want, I want, I want... You don't always get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been a long time since I used Smarty (why not just use PHP), but this seems right:

```
{if isset($smarty.post.last7, $smarty.post.last30, $smarty.post.last60)}
    This is working
{else}
    This is not working!
{/if}
```

Comment: aaaand you've just disproved my comment. No cookie for you

Comment: Just tried that but it's not working on my end.  Also, I've gone over the article you linked to multiple times already, there's only one reference to using `isset` but it didn't give any examples using POST.